# scala play/jquery/image paths

Tags: jquery, playframework

The following jquery code in my javascript does not work. It may be just an issue of escape charcacters, but I fear it runs deeper. Maybe the `@routes` does not work with jquery since twirl is server side?

```
$('#sparseColumnCount').append("ttyyyy"+ "<img src='@routes.Assets.at('images/loading.gif')' >")
```

The following code does not work either. The reason is that everything gets sent through the router, so it cannot be found in routes.

```
$('#sparseTargetCount').html("ttyyyy"+ "<img src='./images/loading.gif' width='28' height='22' '>")
```

**Question**

Can I load images with jquery?

If no, how do I load a simple 'loading gif' on the fly?

**UPDATE**

I have now tried with jsrouter

Contoller

```
 def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(
      JavaScriptReverseRouter("jsRoutes")(
        routes.javascript.Assets.versioned
      )
    ).as("text/javascript")
  }
```

Routes

```
GET     /javascriptRoutes                 controllers.HomeController.javascriptRoutes
```

View

However,

```
$('#sparseColumnCount').append( "<img src="+jsRoutes.controllers.Assets.versioned("/images/loading.gif")+ " />")
```

returns an object. I need it to return a path

Comment: Do you put your js code into twirl template or to separate js file?

Comment: separate js file

Comment: Have you tried to call `absoluteURL` method on `jsRoutes.controllers.Assets.versioned("/images/loading.gif")`? According to documentation it should return complete url string.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: honestly, by the time you responded, I had cheated, loaded the images with Twirl and hidden them with jquery. However, your suggestion is duly noted and I'll try it next time I encounter the issue.